# AJAX call won't send data

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, netsuite

I know there are tons of questions on this already but none of those seem to work. I am trying to send data from a form into a suitelet on NetSuite but it doesn't even send the data. Does anyone see where I am going wrong?

I keep getting Partial Content as the statusText in the console.

```
$("#save").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    signup();
});

var signup = function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var server = $('#server').val();
    var username = $('#user').val();
    var pwd = $('#pwd').val();
    var active = $('#active').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/services/save.ss',
        data: {
            name : name,
            server : server,
            username : username,
            password : pwd,
            active : active
        },
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging in the browser to see if you have any errors?

Comment: In addition to what travis said, make sure `signup` is actually being called. Your code for making an ajax call is correct. (although you're missing a semi-colon on the closing parenthesis of ajax, but it will run without it).

Comment: try to see the console log  and log as (console.log(xhr.responseText))

Comment: Try moving the signup function above the function call. JavaScript functions need to be above where they are called.

Comment: @TravisPettry yes there are no errors and I'm using the console and I'm getting a "Partial Content" as the statusText.

Comment: @ElatedOwl yes signup is being called. It's going into the error function

Comment: @TravisPettry that didn't work either :-/

Comment: @user2573699 The problem is most likely with your service then.

Comment: @ElatedOwl it doesn't reach the service script. I have a log that will show up when it hits the service script. When I sent the data through the form the service script ran fine.

Comment: @user2573699 Are you sure you're hitting the right URL? Are you sure you're sending the right parameters? Are you sure each element you're getting the `val` from is targeting the right element and giving you a value other than `undefined`?

Comment: @ElatedOwl yes. when I look at the post data I'm getting all the correct values from the form, nothing is coming back undefined. It's also going to the right URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to mention `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`.Make your data like this `{ "name ":name,"server":server,"username":username,"password";password,"active":active }` and put it in var then pass it.

```
var jsonData = { "name":name,"server":server,"username":username,"password";password,"active":active };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "/services/save.ss",
      dataType: "json",
      data: jsonData,
      success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function(response){
        console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
      }
  });
```

Make sure your server side code should be correct to catch the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this might work for you by adding 'return false' after signup() as it is called on button click event call OR by adding "async:false," before 'success:' function in ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your suitelet is fully open, if not read up on CORS and how to JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, unless the suitelet is in the same subdomain as the Javascript code, you'll get a "partial content" response.  What's happening is that your AJAX request is being treated as a cross-domain request (read up on CORS as per the previous answer), and Netsuite doesn't handle CORS.

Myself, I've also had no luck with JSONP, either.